# http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I have a problem that I can't seem to figure out. I want to send a http params request from my Angular client to server using below code but I am getting exception:

> http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass

I want clarity about it, did I make any mistakes in Angular or is this a server side problem?

### Auth:

```
login(username: string, password: string) {
    let params = new HttpParams();
    params = params.append('email', username);
    params = params.append('password', password);
    return this.http.post<any>('URL',{params:params})
      .pipe(map(user => {
        if (user && user.token) {
        }
      }),
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35588699/response-to-preflight-request-doesnt-pass-access-control-check)

Comment: @AbhiRam Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53087341/the-access-control-allow-origin-header-has-a-value-http-localhost4200-tha/53683422#53683422

Answer (score 0):

Yes, This is server-side problem not client side.

You need to enable `CORS` for your `localhost` from server side in order to consume API's from your Angular code.

PS: For a quick fix you can install [chrome plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog) to enable `CORS` but this is not recommended approach ever.

Comment: So probably you should go for exact fix that is enable CORS from backend

Answer (score 0):

Modify your server to add the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` to enable cross-origin requests from any domains.

Answer (score 0):

Add configuration in VSCode before run your application(F5)

```
"runtimeArgs": ["--disable-web-security"]
```

in launch.json file